# what should I use as contentType parameter in ParseFile

Tags: android, parse-platform

I use ParseFile and when I want to create a new one with that constructor:

```
ParseFile parseFile = ParseFile(String name, byte[] data, String contentType);
```

what should I use in the contentType pram?

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to send to Parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries it seems I should use [mime types](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/)

Answer (score 1):

[`Guava`](https://github.com/google/guava/) has [`MediaType`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/release19/guava/src/com/google/common/net/MediaType.java) class which has predefined mime types.